# Toggle visibility of ImageButton inside ListView Item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm using a `ListView` with a custom adapter in my application, it contains two `TextView`s an `ImageButton` and an `ImageView` as background image. Now by default the `ImageButton`'s visibility is set to `GONE`. Whenever an item from the list is clicked the `ImageButton` of that item should become `VISIBLE` and if an `ImageButton` is `VISIBLE` in another item it should be set to `GONE`.

I've made changes to the CustomAdapter so that it shows the `ImageButton` when an item (read background `ImageView`) is clicked, however, this leads to my `onItemClick` method in the Fragment.java to not be called. Also, when the item (read `ImageView`) is clicked it does not set the visibility of the previously clicked item's `ImageButton` to `GONE`, I need to click the item again to set that item's `ImageButton` visibility to `GONE`.

Here's the itemlayout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/linearLayout"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bg1" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_key">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottomText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_repeat"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_replay_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@null"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList songList;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public boolean isVisible;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList songList){
        this.songList = songList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public boolean isVisible(){
        return isVisible;
    }

    public void setIsVisible(boolean isVisible){
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.backgroundImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
            holder.topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topText);
            holder.bottomText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomText);
            holder.button_repeat = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_repeat);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SongItem songItem = (SongItem) songList.get(position);
        holder.topText.setText(songItem.getTopText());
        holder.bottomText.setText(songItem.getBottomText());

        holder.backgroundImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.button_repeat.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    holder.button_repeat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else holder.button_repeat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView backgroundImage;
        TextView topText;
        TextView bottomText;
        ImageButton button_repeat;
    }

}
```

[image: Image to explain things better]

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your fragment:

```
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mListView.clearChoices();
            mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mListView.invalidateViews();
        }
    });
```

and modify the getView() of your adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    AbsListView listView = (AbsListView) parent;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.backgroundImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
        holder.topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topText);
        holder.bottomText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomText);
        holder.button_repeat = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_repeat);
     } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    SongItem songItem = (SongItem) songList.get(position);
    holder.topText.setText(songItem.getTopText());
    holder.bottomText.setText(songItem.getBottomText());

    if(listView.isItemChecked(position)){
        holder.button_repeat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.button_repeat.setTag(position);
    }else{
        holder.button_repeat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.button_repeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If you need the Image button click
            int pos = v.getTag();
        }
    });
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```